# How to express "the same" in Russian

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

There seems to be many variants of **the same** in Russian: "**один и тот же**", "**этот же**", "**такой же**", etc.

What rules govern the use of these?

For example, in the following sentences, how do I know which variant to use?

> 1) Why do you wear **the same** clothes everyday?
>
> 2) "Where should we meet?" "**Same** place as last time."
>
> 3) I go to **the same** university as him.

Comment: Roughly saying, "такой же" = "same as"; "тот же" = "the same as", "один и тот же" = "the same".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Один и тот же** – this is used to describe something that doesn't change from one occasion to another, usually with negative connotation:

> Каждый день повторялось одно и то же – он обещал прийти вовремя, но снова опаздывал. // The same thing repeated every day – he kept promising to come on time but was always late.
>
> Каждый год одно и то же – в марте холодно и повсюду грязь. // Every year it's the same – cold in March and dirt everywhere.

**Этот же** – this is used to refer to an object or person, mentioned somewhere before:

> Вчера он заходил в магазин. Этот же человек был замечен на вокзале. // Yesterday he went to the shop. The same man was spotted at the railway station.
>
> Я купил машину в прошлое воскресенье. В этот же день я попал в аварию. // I bought the car last Sunday. On the same day I got into accident.

**Такой же** – this is used to express that object/person has the same qualities as another object/person:

> Ты такой же дурак, как и твой отец. // You are an idiot just like your father.
>
> Гастроскопия - такая же неприятная процедура, как и колоноскопия. // Gastroscopy is a procedure as unpleasant as colonoscopy.

Answer (score 4):

"такой же" = having the same qualities, similar

"один и тот же", "этот же" = exactly that one

Answer (score 3):

I would rather say, that in English many different meanings are expressed with "the same".

**1) Why do you wear the same clothes everyday?**

Here you describe one set of clothing. Answer to question "какую [одежду]?" is "одинаковую", "одну и ту же".

> Почему ты носишь каждый день одно и то же? *(одну и ту же одежду, одинаковую одежду).*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IB9C.jpg

> Квадраты А и В одного и того же *(одинакового)* цвета? Я думала, они разные.

**2) "Where should we meet?" "Same place as last time."**

Answer to question "где?" is "там" or "в [описание] месте".

> Где встретимся? Там же, где в прошлый раз? *(В том же месте, что и [в] прошлый раз?).*

**3) I go to the same university as him.**

Answer to question "какой [университет]?" is "тот же".

> Мы с ним ходим в один [и тот же] университет.

Comment: I'd add an example for "такой же": "he was wearing the same T-shirt as I" – "он был в такой же футболке как и я". And another thing to add: "этот же" can be used instead "тот же", but with an emphasis, like "the very same"

Comment: "На фотографии он в этой же футболке" = he took the T-shirt off me and wear it for the foto. "На фотографии он в той же футболке" = we have two identic T-shirts.

Comment: +1 Такой же should be added with both meanings *similar* and *the same* to make it a perfect answer.

Comment: "They're wearing the same shirt" has two possible meanings in English: they are wearing the same single/literal/physical shirt vs. they are (each) wearing the same brand/style shirt. In Russian there is no ambiguity: "они носят ту же футболку" vs "они носят такую же футболку". This is why some are describing the latter as meaning "similar" though it will often translate as "same".